# Remove words with lowercase letters in them

Tags: javascript, regex

I am reading words from an image(licence) and I know that every word on this licence is uppercase so...If it picks up background noise and returns lowercase letters alone or in words I know that that is not useful/or incorrect information.

From a licence this data is returned....

`aaaa——————————————aESESESsSs—— VICTORIA AUSTRALIA JANE CITIZEN 87652301 FLAT 10 " 77 SAMPLE-PARADE . ‘ KEW-EAST VIC 3102 .\ e ol LICENCE EXPIRY DATE OF BIRTH 20-05-2019 29-07-1983 \ ' ) EICENCE TYRE ‘CONDITIONS Alh 7 al CAR A\ SBEAXYZ 28071985 SN |_vicroads | =< AN e`

One of my points of sanitising this into useful info is to remove all words and letters with lowercase characters. Will I need to split by space, then iterate through each word and remove if it finds lowercase or is there a regex pattern I can use?

I tried this `text = text.replace(/[^A-Z0-9 \n]/g, '')` but would like to also remove full words with lowercase letters as oppose to just all lowercase letters by themselves.

Thanks

Comment: Try `string.match(/\b[A-Z]\w*/g).join(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
/\W*\w*[a-z]\w*/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/4YlydY/1/).

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `\W*` | non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\w*` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `[a-z]` | any character of: 'a' to 'z' |
| `\w*` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally match non whitspace chars without a lowercase char. Then match a lowercase char followed by optional non whitespace chars.

```
[^\sa-z]*[a-z]\S*
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\sa-z]*` optionally match a non whitespace char except a-z
- `[a-z]` Match a single lowercase char a-z
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ2KtN/1)